# How do I completely reinstall Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: system-installation, uninstall

I need to uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 and install it back again.

I installed it alongside windows. I recently uninstalled Windows.

I wish to re install the same version of Ubuntu after this. I really want to do a total clean install. I don't need any files on here, I never saved anything important anyways.

So how should I go about totally removing everything and starting fresh with Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 6):

Boot through a live CD/USB, then Select "Install Ubuntu".

At this step:

[image]

Choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu".  Choose the same option if there are other options available.

This will install a Fresh new copy of Ubuntu on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD or USB, don't install it but use it in Live mode, look for an application called `gparted`, with that you will be able to format the partitions related to Ubuntu or delete these partitions all together.